# Нейронная сеть на Keras Python

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

как с помощью Keras сделать сеть с 5 выходами, надо чтобы каждый выход делал предположение в числах от 1 до 5. Например: вход - [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], выход - [5, 4, 3, 2, 1].

Comment: уточните суть вопроса - это задача классификации или регрессии? И что будет подаваться на вход НС?

Comment: На вход будет подаваться массив из 5 чисел от 1 до 5, сеть должна найти закономерность и выход должен быть массивом из 5 чисел от 1 до 5. Например вход сети должен быть [1,2,3,4,5], выход реверс, т.е. [5,4,3,2,1].

Answer (score 0):

```py
NameOfNetwork.add(Dense(сколько_входов, функция_активации))
...
NameOfNetwork.add(Dense(сколько_выходов, функция_активации))
```

Всё.